# Ipad wont download apps from Safari

Tags: ipad, safari, applications

To be specific, when I try to download an app from Safari, it'll start the download, but then stop and show a message that says, "(App name) cannot be downloaded at this time", then "Done" and "Retry". The Ipad runs on IOS 9.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Are you sure you are downloading in Safari?

Comment: Is this iPad jailbroken?  If not, you won't be able to download from Safari.

Answer (score 1):

To help keep things Mac-loke, apps for ios can only be downloaded from the App Store. Safari or any other site is not allowed to download apps.